# how do i read json data sent with http post in python without any framework?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am writing small python scripts to send json and receive at other end to understand the working of http post and get. I am able to send the json data but i am not aware how to read that json with python.

Here is my python script which posts json data.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pycurl
import json

data = {"name":"username", "pass":"userpass", "job": "userjon"}
data = json.dumps(data)

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://localhost/getRequestData')
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, data)
c.perform()

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
```

I will have another script say decodejson.py running on the same server. And i will do rewrite using apache htaccess like,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule "^getRequestData$" "decodejson.py"
```

now the redirection is success, how do i decode the json in my decodejson.py script.

i have tried running a php script and decoding it with $_POST variable, it works fine.

```
<?php
     echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

I want to understand how to make it work in python.
I am not using any framework here, as you can see i am enabling cgi method.

Please help me solve this. Thanks!

Comment: `json.loads`? Or are you asking something else?

Answer (score 0):

Use requests library. Its simple and easy to use.

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"
>>> requests.post(url, data={}).text  # put your data with data argument
'{"id":"419","createdAt":"2018-11-14T14:18:52.888Z"}'
```